# evaluating expressions in modulo 15 system

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

[image]

Hi !! I tried to find information and examples to solve this **modulo arithematic** problem but couldn't find it.. This is my preparation questions for exam and not assignment.Could someone explain the steps to solve this problem? And, any resource with related examples like this? cheers!!

Comment: You shouldn't be having any problems with the first one. In the second one, realize that dividing by 13 is the same as multiplying by the inverse of 13; hence, you need to find an $n$ such that $13\cdot n\equiv1\pmod{15}$. The last problem does not have a unique answer, because 5 does not have an inverse mod 15.

Comment: got it !! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Just do normally and perform modulo at last: $12+22=34\equiv4\pmod{15}$.

(2) Note that $13\equiv -2\pmod{15}$ so $13^{-1}\equiv-8\equiv7\pmod{15}$. Then do normally: $(-12)\times(-8)=96\equiv6\pmod{15}$

(3) Since $5\cdot n\not\equiv1\pmod{15}$ as $5n-1$ cannot be a multiple of $5$, $5^{-1}$ does not exist and hence $\div$ is not well-defined.

Comment: got 1 & 3 .  not too clear on 2nd after 13 inverse .. could u please explain it briefly? cheers!!

Comment: We want to find $13^{-1}$ so that $13\cdot13^{-1}\equiv1\pmod{15}$. This means $(-2)(13^{-1})\equiv1\pmod{15}$ and it is obvious that $(-2)(-8)=16\equiv1\pmod{15}$

Comment: sorry I probably need to check some rules of inverse on modular arithmetic but still didn't get the section of how u got (-2)(13 inverse) and (-2)(-8) and the values on top is different than the u mention just above .

Comment: First we have $13\cdot13^{-1}\equiv1\pmod{15}$ then we have $13\equiv-2\pmod{15}$. From these two we get $(-2)(13^{-1})\equiv1\pmod{15}$. However since $(-2)(-8)\equiv1\pmod{15}$ we have $13^{-1}\equiv-8\pmod{15}$. And which part do you refer to when you say the values are different?